# Looking for an example regarding hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Does there exists a hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ such that a sequence $\{ x_n \} \subset \mathcal{H}  $ is weakly convergent, but not convergent in the hilbert space norm ?

Comment: There are such a sequence in any infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Can you give an explicit example ?

Comment: Pick $H = \ell^2$ and $x_n = e_n$ (the standard basis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space and pick an orthonormal sequence $\{e_n\}$, that is,
$$(e_n, e_m) = \delta_{nm} = \begin{cases}1&n=m,\\0&n\ne m.\end{cases}$$
Can you show that $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$, but $e_n \not\to 0$?

Hint: Bessel's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence

$$x_n = \sin{n x}$$

in the Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$. By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (or Plancherel's theorem) $x_n$ converges weakly to $0$; however, $x_n$ does not converge to $0$ in the $L^2$ norm.